# How to create a separate NSUserDefaults (other than standard) - which is not shared across extensions?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I work on an SDK which writes to NSUserDefaults.  Occasionally a client's host app will bulk erase the standard NSUserDefaults, trampling on the SDKs data.  The solution would seem to be to not use the "standard" user defaults.  It appears you can use constructor [init(suiteName:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init), but I read elsewhere that if you create an instance like this it will become shared across app extensions under certain conditions that the host may activate (for which my SDK would be unaware).  I would need to keep them separate from each other if they're running in app extension(s), but changing a key name or the suite name isn't a good option because the SDK wouldn't intrinsically know which location it's running in.  Is there a way to create a user defaults instance that behaves like standard but isn't standard?

Answer (score 0):

App extensions have different bundle ID's. So you could use the bundle ID as a prefix to your `suiteName`.

`Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier` will give you the bundle ID of the current executable.

Comment: I appreciate the thought.  I'm considering that, but hoping there's a better way.  I guess that would be one strange suite name, with two reverse domain names smashed together.

Comment: Plus that would make the SDK sensitive to changes to the bundle id.